# How to make ProgressBar "smoother" in updating progress

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I make a ProgressBar smoother in displaying the progress?

Currently I'm using this (it counts up to a specificed time in seconds, in this example `secondsToRun = 120`):

```
public void startBrushing(View view) {
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    int secondsToRun = 120;
    progressBar.setMax(secondsToRun);

    runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    runner.execute(secondsToRun);
}

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

    private String resp;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i <= params[0]; i++) {
                publishProgress(i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                if (i == params[0]) {
                    Log.d("CyCy", "Finished Countdown!");
                    chronometer.stop();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... status) {
        progressBar.setProgress(status[0]);
    }
}
```

If I increase the time of updates (`secondsToRun = 1200` and update it every 100ms and not every 1000ms) it works fine too but it gets a bit inaccurate.

If I use `secondsToRun = 12000` and update it every 10ms it is extremely inaccurate. When the loop says "30 seconds are finished" in real time it is 37 seconds.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "inaccurate"?

Comment: Your problem is your sleep time of 1 second. Can't get any smoother with such a wait time. You could try working with milliseconds, probably only sleep times of maybe 5-25 milliseconds will be smooth.

Comment: @indivisible When quarter of the 120 seconds are finished in the ProgressBar (30s) and are displayed about 37 seconds are finished in real time. Seems that the UI is too slow at updating the progress bar.

Comment: @Blacklight As I wrote above, if I update it every 10ms it gets inaccurate and runs too slow.

Comment: If that's the case why not update based off the actual time (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) instead of counting yourself. That should keep the bar in sync with the real time instead of being subject to the wait time added when the CPU does its thread hopping.

Comment: @indivisible Sounds good and should work! Could you give me a code example? I'm not the best in Java and currently don't know how to realize that :-/

Comment: Android is not a RTOS (realtime OS) so this accuracy will be difficult if not impossible. And like I said, with 1s sleep it won't be smooth ever. See this link, maybe consider using the NDK? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/M2wLfWG9xYE

Comment: @Blacklight The "DeskClock" App from google itself (the clock, alarmclock and timer) is accurate even with long times and is very smooth. Try to set a timer in android 4.x and let it count down from 2 Minutes. The ProgressBar is displayed very well. But I'll read your link and read about the NDK

Comment: @user2765509 My answer regarding accuracy and RTOS was theoretical, I personally don't have any experience about accurate timing. If you get better results natively let us know (may depend on devices though). Try indivisible'S idea first, might work.

Comment: @Blacklight, if `System.getCurrentMillis()` isn't accurate enough for whatever purpose you always have `System.nanoTime()` available.

Comment: @indivisible I'm guessing your idea of using the system-time will be much more accurate than thread-timing already.

Comment: Yeah, there'll always be overhead when changing Threads and that time will be lost in the original implementation. The more accurate you try to get (faster refresh rates) the more the Tread will get run, the more the CPU will be hopping in and out thus increasing the total "lost time" and further diverging from reality. With a long enough timespan and a short enough refresh I'd imagine it adds up noticeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for posting a bit.. late. Here is my solution which is working great currently:

```
int msecondsToRun = 120 * 1000 // If it should run 2 minutes.

startCountdown(msecondsToRun);

private void startCountdown(final long countdownTime) {
  countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdownTime, 10) {
    // The millisUntilFinished thing is for a "pausing" function I implemented.
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      timerProgress = msecondsToRun - millisUntilFinished;

      progressBar.setProgress((int) timerProgress);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // For styling purposes because of the "inaccuracy" of the timer
        // so the progress will be shown as "full"
        progressBar.setProgress((int) msecondsToRun);
    }
  }.start();
}
```

If you have any questions or hints feel free to comment!

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in a comment above you could update your ProgressBar based off the real time instead of your own counter:

I've not tested this so think of it as mildly pseudo-code:

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Void> {

    private long startTime;
    private long progressDurationMillis;
    private long updateFrequencyMillis = 200;     // default 0.2 secs

    // pass in the progress bar max duration in the constructor
    //    so you can set the dialog max value in onPreExecute()
    public AsyncTaskRunner(long progressDurationMillis) {
        this.progressDurationMillis = progressDurationMillis;
    }

    // a second constructor for easy testing of different update values
    // you could test a bunch together in a loop and see which looks best
    public AsyncTaskRunner(long progressDurationMillis, long updateFrequencyMillis) {
        this(progressDurationMillis);
        this.updateFrequencyMillis = updateFrequencyMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        this.startTime = System.getCurrentMillis();
        // set up your dialog here and display
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        long timeExpired = 0;
        try {
            while(true) {
                timeExpired = progressDurationMillis - (System.getCurrentMillis() - startTime)
                publishProgress(timeExpired);
                Thread.sleep(updateFrequencyMillis);

                if (timeExpired >= progressDurationMillis) {
                    Log.d("CyCy", "Finished Countdown!");
                    chronometer.stop();
                    // exit the while loop
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... status) {
        progressBar.setProgress(status[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() {
        // dismiss your dialog here
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, I'd be interested in the accuracy. Like I said above though 500ms will be far from smooth, if I remember right I needed to go down to 5-10ms for a visibly smooth progress.

Comment: Just threw that in as a possible value. I chose to define it at the top of the class to allow for easy manipulation. You could also always add it as a second argument to a second constructor for even easier testing. Actually, I'll edit that in.

Comment: @user2765509, I'd be interested in seeing how the supplied time differs from what the chronometer measures. If you have the inclination to, come back and show us some results.

Comment: @indivisible Posted my current solution a bit late ;)

Comment: @user2765509 Better late than never!  =0p